# Ambiguity with instance variable

Tags: spring, instance-variables

I have one variable say 'x'.Now, i want 'x' should be visible to multiple methods in spring controller class.So i made 'x' as instance variable.Now if multiple users request the same controller , will 'x' creates any ambiguity.If it is, what is the best way to accomplish my need.

And I also got to know that we can make spring controller scope as per request.But Is there any drawback if we create new controller instance per every user request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to hold state in a controller ? Leave it as a singleton and if necessary inject in session or request scoped beans.